# Error while importing SQL database from local to server

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know this question has been asked before but I still couldn't get it fixed. I'm getting a #1046 error while importing my WP database from local to server. Here is what I get :

```
 CREATE TABLE `wp_cntctfrm_field` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `name` char(100) NOT NULL
               ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL a répondu (Translation: MYSQL responded) : Documentation

> 1046 - Aucune base n'a été sélectionnée(translation : no database was selected)

It's the first time I do it so I followed a tutorial but nothing seems to make it work.

Comment: How you try to Import the dump?

Comment: I guess you have first create the database using query "CREATE DATABASE <database name>" then select database which you have created "USE <database name>" then run your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select the target database you want to use to create/populate the database schema in.

You can select the target database at a global level for instance with Mysql Workbench in the left side, right hand click on the database you want to populate and select "Set as default schema".

You can also define the target database upon each SQL query.
For instance with your example, if the target database is named targetdb :

```
CREATE TABLE targetdb.wp_cntctfrm_field ( id int(11) NOT NULL, name char(100) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Please note that the target database must be created first with the appropriate CREATE DATABASE clause.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I figured it out but now I'm supposed to change wp_otions siteurl anbd home to my websites' url but it's still not working :/ When I open the website it says it couldn't connect to the database

Comment: Ok so i changed database to the target database I created, 'root' to the user and password to the user's password. It's still not connecting should I change 'localhost' too ?

Comment: Can you give more precisions ? are you talking about the mysql configuration or the WP one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql -u <user> <DB_name> <<filename>`

or add `use <db_name>;` at top of your dump file